# Why is numpy's covariance slightly different to manually computing?

Tags: python, numpy

I'm just curious, and thought I'd ask this question. How come when I manually compute the covariance matrix of a set of data are my values slightly different to numpy's values?

I have two sets of data `X` and `Y`

```
data = io.loadmat("datafile.mat")['data']
X = data[:,0]
Y = data[:,1]
```

The covariance matrix can be computed like this (by looking at the correlation between X and X, X and Y, Y and X, etc.)

```
n = len(X)
corXX = np.var(X)
corXY = (1/n)*np.dot(X - np.mean(X), Y - np.mean(Y))
corYY = np.var(Y)
covariance = np.array([[corXX, corXY], [corXY, corYY] ])
```

For my dataset, that gives me:

```
array([[ 1.722105  ,  5.34104265],
   [ 5.34104265, 17.72717759]])
```

Whereas using numpy's covariance function `covariance = np.cov(X,Y)` gives me

```
array([[  1.7395    ,   5.39499258],
   [  5.39499258,  17.90623999]])
```

Similar, but not quite the same...

Comment: try a thing, add `bias=True` as an argument for `np.cov` please and compare again.

Comment: Sure thing - that gives the exact same answer now. How come?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By default `np.cov` calculates the unbiased covariance which uses a factor `(N-1)` instead of `N` as you calculated.

If you check the documentation for [`np.cov`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.cov.html) you see that there is an argument (`bias`) to choose from the biased or unbiased versions of the covariance. By default it is set to `false`.

You can read more about the issue behind the use of a different prefactor in [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sample_mean_and_covariance) if you're curious.

Comment: Nice! Would be interesting to know what the stats behind that is.

Comment: You can read the article, but it boils down to the fact that you have a sample and not the whole population, that's why there is this extra correction factor.

Comment: Right. You've just linked the documentation though? Don't see an article.

Comment: Bah, I screwed the links.. correcting ASAP, in any case you can and should consult wikipedia at least ;)

Comment: Should be `(N - 1)` not `(N + 1)`.